# Plupload fails to upload large files to AppEngine Blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore, plupload

I'm writing an application that uses AppEngine's Blobstore API to store files that the user uploads. On the client-side, I use Plupload. It works fine for files up to about 1.5 GB, but around 3 GB or so, upload requests mysteriously fail. A screenshot from the Dev Tools:

[image: POST request to Blobstore has no response status; wasn't even sent]

As you can see, the request fails completely, before it's even sent. Some of the things I noted:

1. The upload shows some progress, usually 1, some intermediate number and then almost immediately, 100 (clearly impossible for such a large file)
2. The "FileUploaded" Plupload event fires

As an aside, I built a [stripped-down application](http://pluploadflash.appspot.com/), that has only one page with Plupload and used that to upload files, it appears to work for > 3 GB files. Any ideas on how I can go about debugging this issue?

**Update**

I tried stepping through the upload. When the "UploadProgress" event triggers, the XHR object that Plupload contains, has a weird error:

`Error: InvalidStateError: DOM Exception 11`

Attached a series of screenshots showing this:

***Breakpoint in the upload progress callback***
[image: Breakpoint in the upload progress callback]

***XHR object has a error status***
[image: XHR object has a error status]

***XHR statusText***
[image: XHR statusText]

Comment: What is the difference between stripped-down and not stripped-down Pluploads in your case?

Comment: Maybe you should try Plupload 2b: http://plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=2528

Comment: @jayarjo The difference between stripped-down and not, is the stripped-down one has just two things: a web page with a Plupload uploader, and an Appengine app that has only 2 servlets: one to create an upload URL and one to handle an upload. The non-stripped-down application is a full-fledged web app that does many other things (file operations, previews etc). Is it possible that because the browser's memory consumption is less when running the stripped-down app, bigger files upload without problems? Whereas the full app already consumes lots of memory on its own, and therefore uploads fail?

Comment: @jayarjo It's worth noting that when I turn on file chunking, stuff works on the browser-side, but Blobstore doesn't seem to work with file chunks. It saves each chunk as a separate file. I failed to update my question with this because we've decided to postpone solving this problem for now.

Comment: @jayarjo Upgrading to a new version of Plupload isn't feasible for us at this stage of development. It's definitely something we will look to do at a later stage.